# How would I save each part of this text file to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file that is updated frequently.

The text file is formatted like so: `1. haha: $44.00, 2. jk: $44.00, 3. jk: $44.00, 4. asdfasdf: $22222.00, 5. asdfasdf: $3333.00,`

How would I save these each to an array so that they can later be called and added together? I basically need to check to see if a name that comes through is the same as one that came through earlier. If so, I need the amounts to be added together.

```
while(!sR.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sR.ReadLine();
    string split = line.Split('$', ',')[1];
    string nameSplit = line.Split('.', ':')[1];

    List<string> namesArray = new List<string>();
    namesArray.Add(nameSplit);

    MessageBox.Show(nameSplit + " " + split);
}

sR.Close();
```

EDIT:

```
decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(split);
                    if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
                    {
                        names[nameSplit] += n;
                        Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        names.Add(nameSplit, n);
                        Console.WriteLine("Failure");
                    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the contents of the array? How should it be divided? Any effort on your side?

Comment: In which part of your code did you get stuck?

Comment: Basically, when people pay the data comes in as above. Only 5 are displayed, and the 5 is removed each time a new name and amount comes through. I have split the name and the amount of the `1.` person. So I have nameVar `haha` and amountVar `44.00`. I then want these to be added to an array so `haha` is [0] and `44.00` is [1]. I then want to be able to see if another person named `haha` had paid. If so, it will add `44.00` and their previous amount which would have been stored int he array before.

Comment: @I4V creating an array to save each variable. I don't know how to add the data to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would opt to create a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). You can check if the name already exists, and if not you can add an item. Else you add the two values.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> names = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

// inside the loop

decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(split);
if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
{
    names[nameSplit] += n;
}
else
{
    names.Add(nameSplit, n);
}
```

You could do the same trick with a `List<decimal>` instead of `decimal` if you intend to keep all the values instead of only the sum.

You add (`Add`) the name to the dictionary. The next time, when the name already exists (`ContainsKey`), it adds (`+=`) the value (`n`) to the previous one.

Comment: It looks correct, could you just explain to me what this is doing just so I can be sure that this is what I want? Thanks!

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse: I edited the answer to include some explanation.

Comment: Thanks, however it is just printing out the `else` statement. Example, I previously had the name `Phil`, when it was run and `Phil` came through again it printed the else, not the if.

Comment: Please view the edit, Patrick. It just always displays `FAILURE`

Comment: I don't know why you say the second case us failure, but that is the intended call for every first time the name pops up. I am not on a console now, so can't test it. If you are certain it is wrong, I will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: You might want to check the contents of the dictionary to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: if I enter the name "Jim" 5 times in to the text file, it just outputs `Failure", although it should have outputted "hoozah!" on the second entry as it had been added on the first try.

Comment: Any idea on what is in the list? A longer text file might be useful too to be able to test it.

Comment: How do I check the contents? sorry.

Comment: Set a break point in Visual Studio. Then hover over the variable name.

Comment: I set a break point on the line `string nameSplit = line.Split('.', ':')[1];` is that correct?

Comment: Or at the Add method.